# Logic Apps - Iterate through Blobs on Azure storage

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure storage account with Input and Archive directories.  I want to:

Check for new XML files in the Import folder.
Read the contents of any files and validate the data.
Rename the XML file and move it to the Archive folder.

I don't want to have to set up a Gateway as I would need to check it was secure.  Therefore, I have set up a recurrence trigger to poll the directory.  This is my logic app so far.

[image]

This is the output I get.

[image]

Here is the error message in full.

````
```{
   "status": 400,
 "message": "The specified resource name length is not within the permissible 
limits.\r\nclientRequestId: f7ed6db1-6ee4-43a3-bd3a-796162f3a58c",
"error": {
"message": "The specified resource name length is not within the permissible limits."
},
"source": "azureblob-ne.azconn-ne-01.p.azurewebsites.net"
}

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the blob [connector reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblobconnector/#get-blob-content) you will find the problem, the Get blob content action ask the blob id and you pass the whole blob property json, that's why it show the error..

The right way is choose the blob id actually the blob path is acceptable. You could refer to my flow.

[image]