# Moving image metadata from Azure Blob Storage into CosmosDB

Tags: metadata, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage

I have several images in a container in Blob Storage that have metadata I want to store in CosmosDB. The images are Jpeg's, Would I have to pull the data into Data Factory or is there a simpler method?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to just write a small console app to loop through all your blob containers and items and insert into Cosmos DB using it's SDK.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to loop through images stored in Blob Storage and store them in Cosmos DB. Please refer to below links. A little tweak and required functionality can be achieved.

1. Using ADF
   [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-SRNiC_qOU)
2. Use Azure Logic App
   [Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272503/logic-apps-iterate-through-blobs-on-azure-storage)
3. Write a custom code and then populate the result into Cosmos DB
   [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet-legacy)

Comment: Thank you very much